# no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Flux<R> conforms to Mono<? extends R>

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Hi I am using the following Flux for iterating the list of records for a JSON payload wherein I am using Flux.fromIterable() function and the return type of main method in Mono.
It shows the below error:

"no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Flux conforms to Mono<? extends R>"

The code snipet is as below:

```java
private Mono<String> createContentForTOC(GenerateToc generateTocRequest, String token, boolean isAutoNumberingEnabled, String projectUrn, String parentEntityUrn, LinkedList<String> volumeList) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(generateTocRequest.getVolumes()).
                flatMap(volume -> createTOCContainer(new Container(projectUrn, TocConstants.VOLUME.toLowerCase(), parentEntityUrn, TocConstants.BODYMATTER, 0),
                        volume.getVolumeTitle().toLowerCase(), token, isAutoNumberingEnabled)
                        .flatMap(containerVolume-> Flux.fromIterable(volume.getUnits()).
                                flatMap(unit -> {
                                    return createTOCContainer(new Container(projectUrn, TocConstants.PART.toLowerCase(),
                                            containerVolume.getEntityUrn(), TocConstants.BODYMATTER, 0), unit.getUnitTitle().toLowerCase(), token, isAutoNumberingEnabled)
                                            .flatMap(containerUnit-> Flux.fromIterable(unit.getChapters()).
                                                    flatMap(chapter -> {
                                                        return createTOCContainer(new Container(projectUrn, TocConstants.CHAPTER.toLowerCase(), containerUnit.getEntityUrn(),
                                                                TocConstants.BODYMATTER, 0), chapter.getChapterTitle().toLowerCase(), token, isAutoNumberingEnabled)
                                                                .flatMap(containerChapter->{
                                                                    return Flux.fromIterable(chapter.getModules()).
                                                                            flatMap(module -> {
                                                                                return createTOCContainer(new Container(projectUrn, TocConstants.MODULE.toLowerCase(),
                                                                                        containerChapter.getEntityUrn(), TocConstants.BODYMATTER, 0), module.getModuleName().toLowerCase(), token, isAutoNumberingEnabled)
                                                                                        .flatMap(containerModule->{

                                                                                            return Flux.fromIterable(module.getSections()).
                                                                                                    flatMap(section -> {
                                                                                                        return createTOCContainer(new Container(projectUrn, TocConstants.SECTION.toLowerCase(),
                                                                                                                containerModule.getEntityUrn(), TocConstants.BODYMATTER, 0), section.getSectionName().toLowerCase(), token, isAutoNumberingEnabled);

                                                                                                    });
                                                                            });

                                                                });
                                                    });
                                        }));
            })));
    }
```

The return type of above function is Mono String

//createTOCContainer function code is as below:

```java
public Mono<ContainerMetadata> createTOCContainer(final Container containerRequest, final String title, final String token, boolean isAutoNumberingEnabled) {
        LOGGER.info("Inside StructureServiceImpl.createTOCContainer");
        String uri = tocStructureContextPath + TocConstants.SEPERATOR + containerRequest.getProjectUrn()
                + TocConstants.SEPERATOR + TocConstants.CONTAINER + TocConstants.SEPERATOR
                + containerRequest.getParentEntityUrn() + TocConstants.SEPERATOR
                + TocConstants.SECTION + TocConstants.SEPERATOR + TocConstants.BODYMATTER
                + TocConstants.SEPERATOR + TocConstants.CHILD_CONTAINER;
        try {
            return createContainerMetaData(containerRequest, token, uri, title)
                    .flatMap(result->{
                        LOGGER.info("Result : [{}]", result);
                        ContainerMetadata containerMetaData = null;
                        containerMetaData = gson.fromJson(result, ContainerMetadata.class);
                        
                        Title title1 = new Title(title);
                        title1.setEs(title);
                        containerMetaData.setTitle(title1);
                        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(title))
                            renameTocContainer(title,  containerRequest.getProjectUrn(),  containerMetaData.getEntityUrn(), token);
                        LOGGER.info("Title has been updated");
                        if(isAutoNumberingEnabled)
                            LOGGER.info("StructureAPIService.addContainerMetaData()");
                        addContainerMetaData(result.toString(), containerRequest, title, token, Boolean.TRUE).subscribe();

                        return Mono.just(containerMetaData);
                    });

        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Container element creation failed for the Container and Title [{} {}]", containerRequest.getParentEntityUrn(), title);

        }
        return Mono.empty();
    }
```

The return type of above function is Mono (ContainerMetaData)

The error showing as:
"no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Flux conforms to Mono<? extends R>" in first call (createTOCContent() function), please let me know if anything need to be corrected. Thanks

Comment: You need to separate nesting into methods and isolate the mappings. It would help you to identify what's wrong.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis while the nesting is definitely making this code unreadable, making it more readable won't solve the issue. The issue is that the declared return type (`Mono<String>`) doesn't match what's being returned (`Flux<String>`).

Comment: @RobSpoor is there any way it can be converted to Mono<String> from Flux<String> without changing main method return type

Comment: @suresh see the answer I just added.

Comment: @RobSpoor Yes, it does. It helps to resolve compilation and IDE errors.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis while it certainly can help resolve errors like you said, it won't help resolve the `Mono` vs `Flux` issue, as that originates from the outermost `Flux` and the method's return type.

Comment: the code is completely unreadable

Answer (score 1):

Your method declares to return a `Mono<String>`. The return value is the result of the outer `Flux.fromIterable` call. That's a `Flux` (probably a `Flux<String>`).

I know of a few ways to solve this:

1. Change the method declaration to return `Flux<String>` (obviously).
2. If the result of the body is a `Flux` with at most one element, call `singleOrEmpty()` on it right at the end. You can also use `single()` if there's exactly one element, or `single(<some default>)` to use a default value if there are no elements.
3. Call `.collect(<some Collector<String, ?, String>>)` right at the end. This will collect all String elements into one String element. Alternatively, use the overloaded `collect` method, `reduce` or `reduceWith`.
4. Call `.last()` or `.last(<some default>)` right at the end, to return the last element (or a default).
5. Call `.next()` right at the end, to return the first element (if there is one).

Comment: Rob Spoor Thanks a lot, these approached are really helpful to resolve the issue.